# How many ways to sharing data between Eclipse RCP plugins?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, treeview, eclipse-rcp, data-sharing

I have a RCP app and a RCP plugin (A) that contributed a Part. There is a TreeViewer (with many items) in the Part. I also defined a popup menu with some menu items (in a file .e4xmi) then registered this menu to the TreeViewer.

I'm writing another RCP plugin (B) that will contribute to the popup menu a menu item and in the handler I want to delete the selected item in the TreeViewer.

The problem is I cannot access the data of the Part (of A) in B. How can A shares the data (TreeViewer) to B? I found a solution is using EventBroker but I want some others. Can you give me some suggestions or hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. For an e4 application the simplest thing to do is have a singleton class containing your data that all plugins can access.

You can specify that a class is a createable singleton to the injection system using:

```java
@Creatable
@Singleton
public class MyDataMananger
{
  ....
}
```

Classes in plugin can then inject the class:

```java
@Inject
MyDataManager manager;
```

You can also

- Use OSGi Services and use a `ServiceTracker`.
- Inject classes created using a `ContextFunction`.
- Simply have a singleton class accessed via a plugin's activator (like `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()`).
- Define an extension point for a service

Comment: Thank about singleton. I also know about this. Can you give me some hints or keywords about others? I have searched about sharing data between plugins but not yet satisfied. Thanks!

Comment: Added a few more methods

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to store your data in the right e4 Context
Explanation of E4 eclipse contexts can be [found here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#the-eclipse-context)
Also if you have access to the TreeVieewer itsefdl, data can be stored by using the `setData(..)` method